# R why the second runif function takes so much time & rbind issue

Tags: r

I want to generate uniformly distributed random numbers twice. I used `profvis` to check the code.

I found that the second `runif` function is taking much more time than the first one. Is there any way to avoid this situation.

L is just an integer between 50 and 100. Please ignore the second line.
[image]

Additionally, in each of my loop, I `rbind` a new record to the current records `data.frame`. This `rbind` operation is also time-consuming.

[image]

If I know the number of records in advance, I can initialize a `data.frame` to store all records. But it cannot be known before the loop ends. Is there any way to append a row to an existing `data.frame` more quickly?

---

Or you can try this simple example to see how the second `runif` turns out to be.

```
library(profvis)

profvis({
  runif(100000,0,1)
  runif(100000,0,1)
})
```

Comment: Which is the value of `L`? Nevertheless they should take the same time, because both `B1` and `O1` represent the same function.

Comment: To append the data at each loop, I'd suggest to use a list instead. You can initialize an empty list using `mylist <- list()` and then use `mylist[[i]] <- mydata` within the for loop to assign the i-est value. After the loop, you can transform the list to a data frame using, for example, `data.table::rbindlist(mylist)`